# Is there a way to build the Dot product of two matrices with different shape?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Is there a way to build the Dot product of two matrices with different shape, without using anything else as pure **python and numpy**?
The shape of the columns should be equal, but the rows should be different. (example below)
Of course I know the brute force way:

```
for i in A:
    for j in  B:
       np.dot(A,B)
```

but is there something else?

Here an example:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.full((4,5),3)
B = np.full((3,5),5)
print(A)
print(B)
result = np.zeros((A.shape[0],B.shape[0]))
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[0]):
        result[i,j] = np.dot(A[i],B[j])
print(dot)
```

Output:

```
A = [[3 3 3 3 3]
 [3 3 3 3 3]
 [3 3 3 3 3]
 [3 3 3 3 3]]

B = [[5 5 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 5 5]
 [5 5 5 5 5]]

result = [[75. 75. 75.]
 [75. 75. 75.]
 [75. 75. 75.]
 [75. 75. 75.]]
```

The coal is to calculate the dot product without two loops. So is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Has nobody a idea?

Comment: Can you post example arrays with an expected output?

Comment: @DarkDrassher34 I added an example

Comment: Why wouldn't `np.dot(A, B.T)` work in your case?